# Ler o arquivo de um input usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu criei um  e gostaria de ler o conteúdo desse input antes de manda-lo para o servidor. Vi que posso fazer isso usando um filereader mas as informações que encontrei estavam meio confusas.

Como posso fazer essa leitura?

A leitura seria de um arquivo txt.

```
var file = document.getElementById("inputmarc");
var fr = new FileReader();

fr.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
fr.onload = function(e) { alert(e); }
```

No HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="inputmarc">
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que tentou fazer? Aproveitando, pode colocar também um exemplo do que deseja fazer, tal como o formato do arquivo que será lido e qual o conteúdo que espera ler nesse arquivo.

Comment: Acho que ainda não posse editar uma pergunta, é um arquivo txt.`var file = document.getElementById("inputmarc");

        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
        fr.onload = function(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }`

Comment: E o código HTML?

Comment: É só um <input type="file" id="inputmarc">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja esse exemplo se te ajuda

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>FileAPI HTML5</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #filecontents {
            border: double;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   Por favor selecione arquivo que será lido:
    <input type="file" id="txtfiletoread" /><br />
    <div>Conteúdo do arquivo:</div>
    <div id="filecontents">
    </div>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            //Check the support for the File API support
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                var fileSelected = document.getElementById('txtfiletoread');
                fileSelected.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                    //Set the extension for the file
                    var fileExtension = /text.*/;
                    //Get the file object
                    var fileTobeRead = fileSelected.files[0];
                    //Check of the extension match
                    if (fileTobeRead.type.match(fileExtension)) {
                        //Initialize the FileReader object to read the 2file
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                            var fileContents = document.getElementById('filecontents');
                            fileContents.innerText = fileReader.result;
                        }
                        fileReader.readAsText(fileTobeRead);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Por favor selecione arquivo texto");
                    }

                }, false);
            }
            else {
                alert("Arquivo(s) não suportado(s)");
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o FileReader funciona somente em navegadores com HTML5.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
        );  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

Fonte: [Fonte do exemplo acima](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=74CM4l-7e4m)

Navegadores compatíveis: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Veja outras infos em:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader